# Preserving independence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose I have three random variables, $X,Y,Z$ with $X$ independent of $Z$, $Y$ independent of $Z$.

Which transformation can I apply to $X,Y$ to that the result is again a random variable independent of $Z$? Or better, for which $f(x,y)$ is $f(X,Y)$ independent of $Z$?

For example $f(x,y) = xy$ does not work because in general $XY$ is not independent of $Z$.

Is there a general result?

Comment: [for the passerby] Example where $XY$ is not independent of $Z$: take $X,Y$ as fair coins, $Z = X \oplus Y$. Then $Z | XY=1$ is the constant random variable $0$, even though $Z$ is a fair coin